# How to find the definite integral of cube of a function whose definite integral is known?

Tags: calculus, integration, functions, definite-integrals

I'm given that the definite integration of some function is equal to $0$.
Now I've to find maximum value of definite integration of cube of same function between same bounds.
How to do it? Please explain.

> I'm writing it in mathematical form.
> $$\int^1 _0 f(x)=0:-1\le f(x)\le1$$
> Find the maximum value of $$\int^1_0 [f(x)]^3$$

Seriously I have no clue to do the question. I tried to draw the graph(experimental) where I kept areas in 1st, 4th quadrants equal so that the integration is zero. Now I'm trying but draw the graph of cubic of same graph. And maximize the area in the first quadrant. I'm thinking about to do it using some graphical calculator and have some visualization of the problem but obviously I have no clue how to do that even.
Thanks for solving the question or giving it time.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96223/discussion-on-question-by-love-invariants-how-to-find-the-definite-integral-of-c).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Summary of results.  $f(x)=1$ for $u\lt x\le 1$ and$f(x)=\frac{u-1}{u}$ for $0\le x\le u$.  To maximize $\int_0^1f^3(x)dx=1-u+\frac{(u-1)^3}{u^2}=\frac{(1-u)(2u-1)}{u^2}=-\frac{2u^2-3u+1}{u^2}=I(u)$  Use elementary calculus to find the maximum. $I'(u)=-\frac{u^2(4u-3)-2u(2u^2-3u+1)}{u^4}$  Set $I'(u)=0$ and get $u=\frac{2}{3}$ and $I(u)=.25$.

Added note $f(x)=-\frac{1}{2}$ for $0\le x\le \frac{2}{3}$.

Comment: Ok sorry. I thought above you meant maximum value of function was 2/3 while it was maximum value of u. Btw answer is 5 so it might be 1/4 or 2/3.

Answer (score 6):

Let $f: [0,1] \to [-1,1]$ be any integrable function satisfies the constraint $\int_0^1 f(x) = 0$. For any $x \in [0,1]$,

$$f(x) \in [-1,1]\quad\implies\quad (1 - f(x))\left(f(x) + \frac12\right)^2 \ge 0$$
Integrating RHS gives us

$$\int_0^1 \left[\frac14 + \frac34 f(x) - f(x)^3\right] dx \ge 0
\implies \int_0^1 f(x)^3 dx \le \frac14
$$
Since this value $\frac14$ is achievable by the function

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}1, & x \in \left[0,\frac13\right]\\ -\frac12, & x \in (\frac13,1]\end{cases}$$
The maximum value of the integral $\int_0^1 f(x)^3 dx$ is $\frac14$.

Comment: I was expecting this kind of solution from math stack exchange. This is trademark of here. Haha you will get simple solution to every problem here except geometry.

Comment: How did you get the first implication?

Comment: The LHS implies that $(1-f(x))\geq 0$, and since $(f(x)+\frac{1}{2})^2$ is squared, it must be non-negative (or equivalently $\geq 0$). Observe that the product of two non-negative numbers is non-negative. Q.E.D.